# ERROR : fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git cloud source repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-source-repos

I am trying to push code from local windows to cloud source repository using cloud sdk the link i was following is

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication

when run the first command in my cloud sdk which is

```
gcloud init && git config --global credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper gcloud.cmd
```

it got run without any issue but it did not generate .git folder in my local folder and when i run the second command that is

```
git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/la-gcp-test/r/demo-repo
```

I got this error

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

All I want to do is to upload a simple index.html file from my local windows machine to cloud source repository using cloud sdk.

Comment: After the first command, what is the output of `ls -a` and `pwd`? It appears that you are inside the `.git` directory when you run the second command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, you're missing `git init` and this must have occurred before you can `git remote add`.

If you haven't initialized a local repo before you come upon `git remote add`, then just `git init` before you `git remote add`

I'm surprised the Google documentation doesn't include it.